# Object is null when passing from AJAX to Controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have looked around to find an answer but nothing helped.

When passing an object from ajax request model binder won't bind it to the model, and the parameter is null.

the AJAX req:

```
function deleteImage(data) {
var s = $('#userServicesDropDownAuth :selected').text()
var i = String(data)
var input = {
    service: s,
    imgId: i
};
input = JSON.stringify({'input': input });
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Actions/RemoveImage',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: input,
    success: function (data) {
        //switch pictures
        //or remove current, and replance with new.
    },
    error: function () {

    }
});
```

}

the controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public string RemoveImage([FromBody]UserWithImageModel input)
    {
         Service service = EnumParser.Parse(input.service);
        //var sessionId = SessionManager.GetCookieSession(service);
        //var bot = Factory.GetBot(service);
        //bot.RemoveImage(sessionId, imgId);


        return null;
    }
```

the object class:

```
 public class UserWithImageModel
{
    public string service { get; set; }
    public string imgId { get; set; }
}
```

when sending the AJAX data like this ( adding a name before the data,  data: JSON.stringify({'input': input })):

```
function deleteImage(data) {
var s = $('#userServicesDropDownAuth :selected').text()
var i = String(data)
var input = {
    service: s,
    imgId: i
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Actions/RemoveImage',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({'input': input }),
    success: function (data) {
        //switch pictures
        //or remove current, and replance with new.
    },
    error: function () {

    }
});
```

}

Comment: Use `[FromBody]` to tell binder where to look for data to bind `public string RemoveImage([FromBody]UserWithImageModel input)`

Comment: The data is not being sent in the correct format. Change `input = JSON.stringify({'input': input });` to just `input = JSON.stringify(input);`

Comment: I tested the [FormBody] & also both,  input = JSON.stringify({'input': input }); to just input = JSON.stringify(input); still nothing

Comment: using the tag resulted in the variable passed just being null, not even the properties being null just the object itself

Comment: Sorry, you were right, [FormBody] did fix the issue, not sure what went wrong on the first try, write the answer so I could approve it! thank you.

Comment: When a parameter has [FromBody], Web API uses the Content-Type header to select a formatter. In this example, the content type is "application/json" and the request body is a raw JSON string (not a JSON object).

Comment: so I guess the controller was trying to format the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[FromBody]` to explicitly tell the model binder where to look for data to bind

```
public string RemoveImage([FromBody]UserWithImageModel input)
```

Also the data is not being sent in the correct format.

Change

```
input = JSON.stringify({'input': input });
```

to just

```
input = JSON.stringify(input);
```

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential issues

1. The variable `i` is not assigned to in your calling code.
2. The controller action is missing the `[HttpPost]` attribute

Some debugging tips:
When you set a breakpoint in the calling code (using F12 in your browser), is the variable `input` assigned?

Do you see the request being made in the browser, if so check the parameter values.

Comment: No idea why the i variable dissapeared, I edited with him, also tested still null, I added a few more pictures explaining & showing it better